# A question about infimum: $k\leq a_i\implies k\leq\inf_i a_i$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $k$ be a constant real number, let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a set with countable cardinality.

if $k\leqslant a$ for all $a\in A$, is it true that $k\leqslant \inf A$?

Must we have $k<a$ for all $a$?

Comment: Is the set bounded?

Comment: @Hawk, If $A$ is not bounded then $k\leq\infty$ is trivial. So yes, let's say it's bounded.

Comment: You only need $k\leq a$  for some $a\in A$ to deduce $k\leq \sup A$. If $k\leq a$ for all $a\in A$ then you have something stronger $k\leq \inf A$

Comment: So from what I see $k \leq a$ for all $a$, but by definition of $\sup$, we must also have $k \leq \sup A.$ I don't see anything forcing $<$

Comment: if you have $k \le a$ for all $a \in A$ then $k \le \inf A$, so the result is certainly true. (Oops, just saw @JulianMejia's comment.)

Comment: Emm.. my mistake. I meant to ask $\inf$, which is just answered by JulianMejia (and copper.hat )

Comment: @qinr: Actually, Julian mentioned it first ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is a non empty set such that $k \le a$ for all $A$. Then $k \le \inf A$.

If $\inf A < k$ then there is some $a \in A$ such that $a < {1 \over 2} (k+\inf A)$, which gives $a < k$, a contradiction.

Take $k=0$, $A=\{0,1,2,...\}$. Then $k = \inf A$.